# How to getLocationOnScreen from a Shortcut or Widget?

Tags: android

When a user presses a shortcut on the screen and that shortcut starts up an activity, how can I get the location of where the shortcut is on the screen?

I have the same question for a widget.  When a user has a widget on the screen and pressing it fires off the setOnClickPendingIntent how can I know the location on the screen where the widget is?

In both scenarios there is no View to run View.getLocationOnScreen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When a user presses a shortcut on the screen and that shortcut starts up an activity, how can I get the location of where the shortcut is on the screen?

<strike>You can't, sorry.</strike>

> When a user has a widget on the screen and pressing it fires off the setOnClickPendingIntent how can I know the location on the screen where the widget is?

<strike>You can't, sorry.</strike>

The only way to get any of that would be to write your own home screen, where you are handling the shortcut presses and app widget taps.

---

**EDIT:** The way the `QuickContactActivity` achieves the effect described in the comments is via `getSourceBounds()`, a method on `Intent`. This `Rect` may or may not be available on any given `Intent`, and therefore any code looking to use it should be able to cleanly react to an `Intent` that has no such value. I can see where `RemoteViews`, the basis for app widgets, use it. I am having a bit more difficulty seeing under what other circumstances the Launcher application uses it. Bear in mind that not all home screens may elect to use it. I apologize for my erroneous original answer.

Comment: That cannot be the case. Android has something called Quick Contacts.  I created an app that puts a shortcut on your home screen.  Pressing the shortcut calls an intent "com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT".  This pops up a contacts "quick contact" box above or under the icon.  If it is impossible to get the position on the screen then how is the quick contact box popping up in the right location?

Comment: @pcm2a: Presumably because Google wrote the home screen in question.

Comment: That is not correct because it works across all phones and all launchers like Adw and launcher pro.

Comment: @pcm2a: I am not aware of any documented and supported information that comes with an `Intent` of the nature you describe.

Comment: There are many apps using it, try out "Contact Widget" free on the market. You can also search googles source (2.1 or later) for "com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT" or ACTION_QUICK_CONTACT to see some examples.

Comment: @pcm2a: You should not be using `com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT` -- anything with `com.android` means it is not part of the Android SDK. In fact, `ACTION_QUICK_CONTACT` is specifically excluded from the SDK. Do not use it. That being said, I will amend my answer, as I found what you were looking for.

Comment: Using ACTION_QUICK_CONTACT is much easier than creating a whole activity just to call showQuickContacts regardless of what "Google" wants. The various example apps I mention on the market are doing that as well.  However, for my original question using getIntent().getSourceBounds() works perfectly!  I was driving myself crazy trying to find a solution.